# ASP.NET (C#) - vs PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Is it possible to create a login/registration system on my site without using any of the bulit-in stuff from ASP.NET - just like you can do in PHP? I've almost completely forgotten everything I learned about ASP.NET - but I don't mind starting over again.

I'd rather roll my own login-registration system in ASP.NET than use an existing one. I seem to learn better this way.

Comment: Thats the difference between open-source and Microsoft. Choose whatever you feel better about. Deploying ASP.NET apps is much more expensive though.

Comment: Could you perhaps remove all the subjective material before your question gets closed. Reducing it to the last two paragraphs should do the trick

Comment: @AbiusX: That used to be the case years ago, but hasn't been for some time now.  There are $5-10/mo ASP.NET hosts that are quite capable.  AppHarbor is also an affordable option for many sites, with a great deployment story.

Comment: @Dave Ward - Yeah, I'm with WinHost, that have a cheap one for $4.95/month (however, they have only recently changed it to quarterly)

Comment: @Dave: Windows servers are paid, Have much less durability, stability and peformance. Hence require more hardware and more man-power to keep them working and more money to buy software, all the more reason to be more expensive.

Comment: @AbiusX: I run a handful of Ubuntu servers and Windows 2008 (some R2) servers.  Neither are noticeably more or less stable than the others, nor does admin'ing either OS require more or less work.  They both have their advantages and disadvantages, but the difference in price and maintainability is entirely negligible these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You sure can. .Net comes with many useful features, but you still have an option to roll your own. Its just a framework, you can extend it anyway you imagine.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

It simplifies ASP.NET, including providing a cleaner implementation of the membership providers that you've used in the past, but also has the full power of ASP.NET under the hood.  If you're trying to find a bridge between PHP and ASP.NET for simple projects, that's a great compromise.

Comment: Thanks, @David - WebMatrix is exactly what got me thinking about ASP.NET again. I downloaded and installed it and played around with it for hours last night (which is why I woke up too late this afternoon :-P)

Answer (score 0):

Membership providers is one of the things in .NET that I moved away from when I started back in version 2.0. Although it provided the high-level functionality, it kinda removes you from having the control over low-level details. The .NET framework library is huge that you can use little bits of pieces of it to create your own custom functionality, which in your case is the login/registration system.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a
>   login/registration system on my site
>   without using any of the bulit-in
>   stuff from ASP.NET - just like you can
>   do in PHP?

Well, it's a turing-complete programming language.* Ergo, yes. Yes you can. This seems like the actual question you're asking, and while you *can* do this, you *shouldn't* do this, ***unless*** you're in the business of writing ASP.NET login/authentication frameworks.

*ok, ASP.NET itself is not a language, it's a platform. All of the languages, however, compile to MSIL which is most definitely turing-complete, which means that you can indeed do the things that you wanted.

> I've almost completely forgotten
>   everything I learned about ASP.NET -
>   but I don't mind starting over again.

How does that work again? If you're using Visual Studio and you think you know what it is you want to do, intellisense does all the work for you. And the C-like syntax of C# and the similar syntax of VB means that you really should be able to pick it back up really quickly. I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.

> I'd rather roll my own
>   login-registration system in ASP.NET
>   than use an existing one. I seem to
>   learn better this way.

This reads as "I'm too stubborn to get things done quickly, and I don't care if there are security loopholes".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I disagree with you on your last statement though. I'm one of the most impatient people I know, all I ever want is to have things right now, however I would rather have more control over what I am doing and spend an extra few days/weeks/months doing it than use something that already exists, which in the past never worked properly to begin with. Yes, obviously someone starting out will not be able to build the most secure login/registration system, but people learn fgrom their mistakes*. That's something that MS hasn't been able to do in a lot of cases.

Comment: @Lucifer have you even looked at the aspnetdb that they offer? You can override all the parts that you don't like and you can use all the parts that you do like. If you can find something that doesn't give you granular control that you need then I want to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a bit of an alternative to rolling your own. I know the ASP.Net Membership model is painful if you need to have control over the low-level details. So, I've written my own authentication library with the goal of giving you full control over how it goes in the database, yet also keeping the secure bits out of reach. This means you can change how things work, without fear of making your site insecure.

My library is named [FSCAuth](http://www.binpress.com/app/fscauth/231). It's BSD licensed. It is aimed to be dead simple to suit to your needs, while being secure enough that even if your database got leaked it'd still take hackers a few decades to decode a password.